# Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I was trying to create a new mail form on click of a button in outlook web add-in and I use [displayNewMessageForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.6/office.context.mailbox?view=office-js#displaynewmessageformparameters). The function works fine in Web browser and Outlook desktop. But the same function wont work in Outlook mobile.

Have you guys have this working in your outlook mobile?

**Manifest for mobile:**

```
 <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <!--Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <!--  Up to 6 Groups added per Tab  -->
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                  <!--  Launch the add-in : task pane button  -->
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle"/>
                      <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                  <!--Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <!--Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee-->
          </DesktopFormFactor>

          <MobileFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
              <Group id="mobileMsgRead">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="TaskPaneBtn">
                  <Label resid="residTaskPaneButtonName" />
                  <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="icon32" />

                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="icon32" />

                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="icon32" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="residTaskpaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </MobileFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon16.png"/>

          <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon32.png"/>

          <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon80.png"/>

        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
          <!--<bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>-->
          <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/home.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="residTaskpaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/home.html"/>
          <!--<bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/home.html"/>-->
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="test codeColumn"/>
          <bt:String id="customTabLabel" DefaultValue="test codeColumn"/>
          <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="test codeColumn"/>
          <bt:String id="residTaskPaneButtonName" DefaultValue="test codeColumn"/>
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="test codeColumn"> </bt:String>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="test test test">

          </bt:String>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
```

Update: If you guys want it only for mobile then use below code

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url,
    { height: 75, width: 80, requireHTTPS: true });
```

Where Url variable can be like this

```
var url = "mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again";
```

Answer (score 1):

`displayNewAppointmentForm` (in your title) and `displayNewMessageForm` (in your question) are two different functions. The [`displayNewAppointmentForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/Office.context.mailbox#displaynewappointmentformparameters) function is not supported in Outlook for iOS or Outlook for Android. In the same time [`displayNewMessageForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.6/office.context.mailbox?view=office-js#displaynewmessageformparameters) function will work on mobile devices when you properly specify support of mobile in your manifest file. For more information read the [Add support for add-in commands for Outlook Mobile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-mobile-support) article.

Comment: I've updated the title and question. Is there any changes that needs to be done in manifest ? 
I had referred the same link to add mobile form factor to manifest.

Comment: Outlook Mobile don't support displayNewMessageForm and displayNewAppointmentForm as of now. The support for display* APIs are in pipeline and will be available soon.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility: is there any workaround for that ? i tried to use mailto but didn't work in mobile.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility:  I tried out displayDialogAsync and it worked well for mobile only. Please refer the question for changes

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility You are probably mistaken [`displayNewMessageForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox#displaynewmessageformparameters) with [`displayMessageForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox#displaymessageformitemid). The first one supported in mobile and the second does not, according to documentation. Please review your comment.

Comment: @aditya The posted manifest is incomplete and displays only VersionOverrides v.1.1 as of I cannot verify validity of it. Please refer to documentation on [Office add-ins manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1) and if you have issues with your manifest post it as separate question.

Answer (score 0):

displayNewMessageForm didn't work for me hence i am using

Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url,
    { height: 75, width: 80, requireHTTPS: true });

var url = "mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again";